# How to rig two hands to item for RIGIFY

Tags: rigging, bones, parent, rigify

[image]

i want too connect both hands of my rigify rig to this sword, i tried the ik hands too weapon but i dont know how to do that for rigify, as which layer of bones too turn into ik or if even possible?

Comment: This isn't a great question ATM, because you haven't described what you tried when you say "only one can connect".  Probably the best thing to do is show your best effort to making this work in a linked file.

Comment: @Nathan i remade the questions now sorry, i was tired when i first made it : D

Comment: Have you tried a *Child Of* bone constraint for both IK hands bones (hand_IK.*)?

Comment: @Blunder when i do that only one hand at a time can be connected not both

Comment: There are 2 two hands, give each a *Child Of* bone constraint. Why should this not work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsIDH.gif - The "sword" is keyframed & has its own armature with just one bone. The shoulder is keyframed. The hands have the bone constraints and follow the sword.

Comment: @Blunder okay now i had understand just learnt about constraints

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure we were talking about the same thing. There are *bone* constraints and *object* constraints. Don't confuse them. The bone constraints can be added in *Pose* mode, one for the bone of the left hand and one for the bone of the right hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134282/discussion-between-cyborg-primate-and-blunder).